# How to create multiple copies with unique names of a file and put new copies into multiple folders in Python?

Tags: python, file-rename, file-copying

Dear all please help me to clarify the way of thinking which could solve my issue.

In Python, **I want to write a code that produces multiple copies with unique names (based on some rule) of a single file and put all new copies into multiple folders.** I will demonstrate some picture.

[image: A scheme of a project]
All the structure I created before.

And now I want to clone file "tile.png" and produce its copies as: '0.png', '1.png', and so force. These names actually based on a rule `png_file_names = [j for j in range(0, 2 ** zoom)]`. After I have the exact amount of copies of a file 'tile.png' with new names I want to copy them all into each subfolder: '0', '1', '2', '3' which you can see in my three.

As I understand I need to apply several loops. Thank you all! This is my code that I have for now:

```
def create_copies_of_a_tile (zoom):
    path_to_the_project = 'D:/ms_project'
    os.chdir(path_to_the_project)
    for j in range (0, 2**zoom):
        shutil.copy2('tile.png', '{}.png'.format(j))
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Show us what you did.

Comment: Yes, for sure! Thank you for a tip.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple copies in a single directory, then move them to other directiories? Copying directly to those directories would be simpler.

Comment: @Błotosmętek, I am doing a trial execution of a code, I need to try it with one single file and later on I will do it with a set of different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial executions I found solution:

```
def create_copies_of_a_tile (zoom):
    path = 'D:/ms_project/tiles/'
    for zoom_level in range (zoom_min, zoom + 1):
        subfolders_path = os.path.join(path, str(zoom_level))
        for xtile_number in range(0, 2 ** zoom):
            sub_subfolders_path = os.path.join(subfolders_path, str(xtile_number))
            for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(sub_subfolders_path):
                os.chdir(dirpath)
                for j in range(0, 2 ** zoom):
                    shutil.copy2('D:/ms_project/tile.png', '{}.png'.format(j))
```

It is working, but I do not understand one thing. When I delete `dirnames, files`  from a pre-last "for statement" `for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(sub_subfolders_path):` (I believe I do not need that parts), I do have an error:

> TypeError: chdir: illegal type for path parameter

Could somebody be so kind and explain to me what is going on? Thank you

And also I was wondering if it is possible to simplify my code a bit. Thank you, all)

And there is one more question how to apply sorting of my folders that I have on the picture? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This script will copy the file to sub-directories named 0,1,2... after creating the sub-directories:

```
import shutil, os

def copytoSub(filename, zoom):
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]

    for i in range (0, 2**zoom):
        i = str(i)
        newfile = i + extension
        os.mkdir(i)                                     # make i named subdir
        shutil.copy2(filename, i + os.sep + newfile)   # copy i named file to i named subdir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    copytoSub("copy.py", 3)
```

*Note: I don't assume you need the copied files of the original file in the current working directory, since the original file, *tile.png*, is already there, I assume you just need to make copies of it in sub-directories.